# Load more data after scroll PHP AJAX Mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli, helper

Hello guys and first of all sorry for my bad english. I just need some help for one script how i can make this script to load more data after scroll when they coming they can see only 5-10 result and when they scroll down will get more.

I will share the code that is being asked and where I need to do it

**user_list.php**

```
    <?php
$rank_ico  = 0;
$sex_ico = 0;

function ico($r, $o){
        if($o == 1){
            if($r == 1 ){ return '<i class="u_ico fa fa-user" style="font-size:18px;"></i>'; }
            else if($r == 2){ return '<i class="v_ico fa fa-heart" style="font-size:16px;"></i>'; }
            else if($r == 3){ return '<img src="../images/police-badge.png" class="m_ico" title="Полицай" />'; }
            else if($r == 4){ return '<i class="a_ico fa fa-star" style="font-size:17px;"></i>'; }
            else if($r == 5){ return '<i class="sa_ico fa fa-star" style="font-size:17px;"></i>'; }
            else { return ''; }
        }
        else {
            return '';
        }
}
function sex($s, $g){
    if($g == 1){
        if($s == 1){ return "<img src='/css/themes/Fancy_gold/icon/male-icon.png' width='20' height='20' class='boy' />"; }
        else if ($s == 2){ return "<img src='/css/themes/Fancy_gold/icon/female-icon.png' width='20' height='20' class='girl' />"; }
        else { return ''; }
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}

$load_data = 'setting.allow_avatar, setting.allow_private, setting.allow_theme, setting.default_theme, setting.language,
 setting.timezone, setting.allow_ignore, setting.allow_friend, setting.ico, users.user_access, users.user_rank, users.user_roomid,
 users.user_name, users.user_theme, users.guest';

require("config1.php");

if($data['ico'] == 1){
$rank_ico  = 1;
$sex_ico = 1;
}

if($data["user_access"] >= 1 && $access == 'on'){

    $data_list = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_name, user_color, user_rank, alt_name, user_tumb, user_status, user_access, user_sex FROM `users` WHERE `user_roomid` = {$data["user_roomid"]}  AND `user_status` <= 2 AND `user_access` != 2 AND `user_access` != 0 ORDER BY `user_status` ASC, `user_rank` DESC, `user_name` ASC ");
    if ($data_list->num_rows > 0)
    {
        echo "<div id=\"container_user\">";
        echo "<ul>";
        while ($list = $data_list->fetch_assoc())
        {
            if($list["alt_name"] == ""){
                $alt = "$notsetyet";
            }
            else{

                $alt = $list["alt_name"];
            }
            $uavatar = $list['user_tumb'];
            if($uavatar == "default_avatar_tumb.png" || $list['user_rank'] < $data['allow_avatar']){
                $avatar_path = "$icon_path";
                $uavatar = "default_avatar_tumb.png";
            }
            else {
                $avatar_path = "avatar";
            }
            $avatar = "<img class=\"avatar_userlist\" src=\"$avatar_path/$uavatar\"/>";
            if($list['user_status'] == 1){
                $away = $list['user_color'];
            }
            else {
                $away = "away";
            }
                if($list['user_access'] == 1){
                    echo '<li class="users_option">
                            <div class="open_user  hover_element sub_element">
                                ' . $avatar . '<p title="' . $alt . '" class="' . $away . ' usertarget" id="' . $list[user_name] . '"><s>' .$list["user_name"] . '</s></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="option_list">
                                <ul class="user_option_list" value="' . $list[user_name] . '">';
                                    echo "<li class=\"user_option_separator get_info\" value=\"get_info\">$usinfo</li>";
                                    if($list['user_name'] !== $data['user_name']){ 
                                        if($data['user_rank'] >= 3){
                                            echo "<li class=\"user_option_separator get_unmute\" value=\"get_unmute\">$usunmute</li>";
                                        }
                                        if($data['user_rank'] > 4){
                                            echo "<li class=\"user_option_separator get_kill\" value=\"get_kill\">$usdelete</li>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                echo "</ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>"; 
                }
                else {
                    echo "<li class=\"users_option\">
                            <div class=\"open_user  hover_element sub_element\">
                                $avatar<p title=\"$alt\" class=\"$away usertarget\" id=\"{$list["user_name"]}\">{$list["user_name"]} " . ico($list['user_rank'], $rank_ico) . sex($list['user_sex'], $sex_ico) . "</p> 
                            </div>
                            <div class=\"option_list\">
                                <ul class=\"user_option_list\" value=\"{$list["user_name"]}\">";
                                    echo "<li class=\"user_option_separator get_info\" value=\"get_info\">$usinfo</li>";
                                    if($list['user_name'] !== $data['user_name']){ 
                                        if($list['user_rank'] >= $data['allow_private'] && $data['user_rank'] >= $data['allow_private']){ 
                                            echo "<li class=\"user_option_separator send_private\" value=\"{$list['user_name']}\">$usprivate</li>"; 
                                        }
                                        if( $list['user_rank'] < 3 && $data['guest'] != 1 && $data['user_rank'] >= $data['allow_ignore']){
                                            echo "<li class=\"user_option_separator get_ignore\" value=\"get_ignore\">$usignore</li>";
                                        }
                                        if( $data['guest'] != 1 && $data['user_rank'] >= $data['allow_friend']){
                                            echo "<li class=\"user_option_separator get_friends\" value=\"get_friends\">$usfriends</li>";
                                        }
                                        if($data['user_rank'] >= 3){
                                            echo "<li class=\"user_option_separator get_mute\" value=\"get_mute\">$usmute</li>";
                                            echo "<li class=\"user_option_separator get_kick\" value=\"get_kick\">$uskick</li>";
                                        }
                                        if($data['user_rank'] > 3){
                                            echo "<li class=\"user_option_separator get_ban\" value=\"get_ban\">$usban</li>";
                                        }
                                        if($data['user_rank'] > 4){
                                            echo "<li class=\"user_option_separator get_kill\" value=\"get_kill\">$usdelete</li>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                echo "</ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>";                     
                }
        }   
        echo "</ul><div class=\"clear\"></div></div>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "<ul>
            <li>Room empty</li>
        </ul>";
}
```

**function.js**

```
    user_reload = function()
{
    if(firstLoad == 1 && width > 1024){
        $('#chat_panel').animate({right:"+="+optionSize},400);
        dataControl = "1";
        $.ajax({
            url: "system/user_list.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#chat_panel .panel_element").html(html);
            },
        }); 
        firstLoad = "0";
    }
    else if (dataControl != 1){
        return false;
    }
    else if ($('.option_list:visible').length){
        return false;
    }
        $.ajax({
            url: "system/user_list.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#chat_panel .panel_element").html(html);
            },
        });
}
```

Comment: Just use LIMIT and OFFSET in your sql query and `$( window ).on('scroll')` event in javascript